# How can I disable the HD button in JWPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I manage a web streaming and archiving site that implements a JWPlayer in some circumstances; and I would like to figure out how I can remove the HD button from the control bar, without removing the whole control bar.

This sort-of falls on the question of whether or not JWPlayer automatically adds the HD button if it detects a header from the RTMP server; but I don't believe that it should be receiving such a header... I'd have to flip around in my server though.

Moral of the story - does anyone know how I can drop the HD button out of JWPlayer manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom skin.
Look [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins) and at the skin [reference](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413071-skin-xml-reference) for more info and basic skins.
To disable the hd button you need to remove the `hdButton`, `hdButtonOver` and `hdButtonOff` elements from the xml:

```
<element name="hdButtonOff" ...... />
<element name="hdButton"......./>
```

Once you get the skin you load it:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    skin: "mySkin/mySkin.xml"
});
```

Comment: And I presume there's no way for me to use multiple skins ( with a priority )? Seems like a bit of reach lol. I think the trick would be to pull a copy of my current skins XML and tweak it? Seems reasonable... Thanks either way - this answers my question. I was hoping there would be an easier way; but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: Now to figure out where I'm going to find the XML for the provided skin... Bleh. Couldn't just be easy.

Comment: Only one skin per player. You can comment out the sections of the XML that you wish to eliminate.

Comment: Any way I can get a copy of the XML for a cloud-based skin?